# create table on Upgrade

Tags: android, sqlite

I have been trying to get this right but i dont know what i am missing. I have an android app and I wish to add 1 more table to it.However i am not able to do it and I have no Exceptions as well(dont like these silent killers!!).

Below is my code my SQLiteHelper class

```
public class DbCreator extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public DbCreator(Context context) {

    super(context, Constants.DB_NAME, null, Constants.NEW_VERSION);//NEW_VERSION=2

    this.myContext = context;
}

//Rest of code

//Checks if DB is present and create if reqd.
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (dbExist) {
        // do nothing - database already exist
    } else {

        // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
        // the default system path
        // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
        // database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database : " + e);

        }
    }

}

    //Check DB is present
    private boolean checkDataBase() {

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {
        String myPath = Constants.DB_PATH + Constants.DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.v("DB", "No DB");
        // database does't exist yet.

    }

    if (checkDB != null) {

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from local assets-folder to the just created
 * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
 * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getResources().openRawResource(
            R.raw.diary_database);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = Constants.DB_PATH + Constants.DB_NAME;

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

    //**This is the problem area
    @Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Constants.log(TAG, "Upgrading started..."+db.getVersion() );
    if (db.getVersion() == Constants.OLD_VERSION) {
            db.beginTransaction();
        Constants.log(TAG, "Upgrading started...transaction");
        db.execSQL("create TABLE Thought(  StartDate DATETIME, Content TEXT, EndDate DATETIME, Title TEXT )");
        db.setVersion(Constants.NEW_VERSION);//NEW_VERSION=2
            db.endTransaction();
        Constants.log(TAG, "Upgrading started...transaction finished");

    }

}
```

Worst part is i see all the logs happening and even the query runs successfully when i do it on console.

---

Edits

My DB does not gets updated :-

I have pulled my DB from emulator and even seen the logs from the version no.is not changed.I use below lines in my activity from to see DB version.

```
DbCreator dbCr = new DbCreator(this);
SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = dbCr.getMyDatabase();
Constants.log(TAG, "Db Version : "+myDataBase.getVersion());
```

Comment: How are you determining that it hasn't worked?

Comment: @Barak: have added logs.see edits..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I strongly encourage you to switch to [`SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper), which has the whole package-the-database-in-the-app pattern worked out.

Tactically, you are not committing your transaction. The proper recipe for multi-statement transactions is:

```
try {
  db.beginTransaction();

  // do SQL here

  db.setTransactionSuccessful();
}
finally {
  db.endTransaction();
}
```

Without the `setTransactionSuccessful()` call, `endTransaction()` will do a `ROLLBACK`.

Comment: yes it gets done .Just tried db.setTransactionSuccessful() but even SQLiteAssetHelper seems very nice and easy.I was thinking of using app version as a check in onUpgrade and having the DB with new table in my asset.so this way new users will have even latest table.

Comment: Good to know about AssetHelper.