# Replace the database file in an app in the next update

Tags: android, android-sqlite

My app has a database file in the assests directory and the app imports it when the app is run for the first time or the database doesn't exist. I would like to replace the database with a database which I have, when the user updates the app for the next time.
It should only run when the user updates it, so that no data is lost.

Can somebody please help me?

This is my code: http://pastie.org/private/bni5iwbob1oklyxx5atolq#66

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364154/create-table-on-upgrade

Comment: Ok thanks, let me try it! :)

Comment: DO I have to manually change the database version number in the database I currently have?

Comment: if you are using child of SqliteOpenHelper for DB operations then u can specify new version of DB inside constructor. take a look at the source thats attached to question

Comment: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper is worth seeing

Comment: I am not able to get it to work. Can you please check the code and help me resolve it?

Comment: change Db version in here ---> public DbImportHelper(Context context) {
  super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1); to 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update your Db version that you have used in constructor

```
public DbImportHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

This way [onUpgrade](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)  will be called.
When you initialize your DB the System checks the current version of DB present on Device. If the version is not matched then your onUpgrade or onDownGrade method is called.

so you can change constructor to something like

```
public DbImportHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 2);
    this.myContext = context;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

One Suggestion avoid using magic numbers like 1,2,55 etc
you can assign a constant to them.this way you wont have to search your code all the time.